# Multithreading with .NET controls

Tags: .net, multithreading, winforms, user-controls

I would like to understand why the following throws an exception:

```
    Dim t As New Threading.Thread(Sub()
                                      Dim x As New PictureBox
                                      Invoke(Sub() Controls.Add(x))
                                      x.Location = New Point(1, 0) 'here
                                  End Sub)
    t.Start()
```

The commented line throws an exception:

```
Control accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.
```

But `x` **was** created on thread `t`, wasn't it?

If I make the assignment *before* `Controls.Add`, it works. Does `Cotrols.Add` somehow change which thread `x` belongs to? Why?

**Motivation:**
I have 10-20 SWF player controls on my form, all of which play flash movies simultaneously, and it really lags if I put all of them on one thread, so I need multithreading.

Answer (score 0):

Dave,
This error is because the controls can only be updated from the main thread or the UI thread( which is the thread on which these controls are created on). This is called Thread affinity. Suggest you read [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28485/Beginners-Guide-to-Threading-in-NET-Part-of-n) article to understand more about this.